# How to use a std::mutex in a class context

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, cross-compiling

i'm having some trouble using a C++11 std::mutex

in my class I have a variable called semaphore of type std::mutex.

So I positioned my semaphore.lock() and semaphore.unlock() before and after my critical section

```
class Database {
public:
Database(string, string, string, string);
virtual ~Database();

struct sMyHome getMyHome(void);
struct sPhysical getPhysical(int);
struct sSystemInfo getSystemInfo(void);
void commitSystemInfo(struct sSystemInfo);
struct sTSensors getTSensors(int);
struct sWireless getWireless(int);
struct sWirelessConf getWirelessConf(int);
struct sWirelessStatus getWirelessStatus(int);

private:
void queryMyHome(void);
void queryPhysical(int);
void querySystemInfo(void);
void queryTSensors(int ID);
void queryWireless(int ID);
void queryWirelessConf(int ID);
void queryWirelessStatus(int ID);
string toString(int);

struct sMyHome MyHome;
struct sPhysical Physical[4];
struct sSystemInfo SystemInfo;
struct sTSensors TSensors[32];
struct sWireless Wireless[64];
struct sWirelessConf WirelessConf[64];
struct sWirelessStatus WirelessStatus[64];

MYSQL *connection;
mutex semaphore;
};
```

this is part of the main, where I retrieve the error:

```
 Database db = Database("192.168.1.10", "****", "******", "******");
```

but the cross-compiler says

```
../main.cpp:8:73: error: use of deleted function 'Database::Database(const Database&)'
  Database db = Database("192.168.1.10", "root", "raspberry", "DomoHome2");
                                                                     ^
In file included from ../main.cpp:2:0:
../Database.h:79:7: note: 'Database::Database(const Database&)' is implicitly deleted      because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class Database {
   ^
../Database.h:79:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)'
 In file included from ../Database.h:12:0,
             from ../main.cpp:2:
/Volumes/rpi-crosscompiler-toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.2/mutex:128:5: error: declared here
 mutex(const mutex&) = delete;
 ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

and this is my constructor:

```
Database::Database(string Address, string Username, string Password, string Database) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
connection = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_real_connect(connection, Address.c_str(), Username.c_str(), Password.c_str(), Database.c_str(), 0, NULL, 0);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to copy  `Database` object, but it is non-copyable. Probably because it has a `mutex` data member. I can't see why the mutex should be static BTW.

Comment: You're not providing enough of your code. Your error messages are impossible to interpret unless you provide more code.

Comment: You aren't showing the relevant code, and that's some problem in ***your*** code ([check this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)). But anyway check the various [auto lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) features provided from the standards to lock/unlock synchronization items.

Comment: Added more code, hope this help to clarify the situation

Comment: Calling a `std::mutex` `semaphore` does not make it one. I would suggest you use a different name, in case some day you add an actual semaphore to your program, and someone gets completely befuddled...

Comment: @AngeloCassano Using the current standard's classes, a _'semaphore'_ actually would be constituted using a [condition variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`std::mutex` is neither copyable nor movable. Including one in your class necessitates that your class becomes non-copyable (-movable) as well. If you want your class to be copyable or movable, you will have to tell the compiler how objects of your class are to be copied or moved by implementing copy/move construction/assignment yourself. [For example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93877f78068b3b1e):

```
class synchronized_int {
  mutable std::mutex mtx;
  int value;
public:
  synchronized_int(int v = 0) : value(v) {}

  // Move initialization
  synchronized_int(synchronized_int&& other) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(other.mtx);
    value = std::move(other.value);
    other.value = 0;
  }

  // Copy initialization
  synchronized_int(const synchronized_int& other) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(other.mtx);
    value = other.value;
  }

  // Move assignment
  synchronized_int& operator = (synchronized_int&& other) {
    std::lock(mtx, other.mtx);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> self_lock(mtx, std::adopt_lock);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> other_lock(other.mtx, std::adopt_lock);
    value = std::move(other.value);
    other.value = 0;
    return *this;
  }

  // Copy assignment
  synchronized_int& operator = (const synchronized_int& other) {
    std::lock(mtx, other.mtx);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> self_lock(mtx, std::adopt_lock);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> other_lock(other.mtx, std::adopt_lock);
    value = other.value;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Comment: Would you mind commenting a little on what all you're doing on the Move/Copy Assignment?  I would've thought just two `lock_guards` statements on their own would be sufficient-- it looks like though you lock both of them using `lock` and then pass the locks to a `lock_guard`, presumably so they automatically unlock at end of scope.   I'm just curious why you did it this way.

Comment: @Jason Whenever a multithreaded program blocks waiting on mutex A while holding mutex B, it runs the risk of deadlock: if another thread holds mutex B and simultaneously blocks waiting on mutex A, neither thread will ever wake and make progress again. The standard library provides [`std::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) as a tool to lock multiple locks while avoiding deadlock. Your analysis of the remainder of the code is correct: once `std::lock` has locked the two mutexes, I have `lock_guard`s adopt each mutex so they will properly be unlocked upon leaving the scope.

Answer (score 4):

Declare your mutex dynamically and not statically.

At your Database class header declare the mutex as a pointer, like that:

```
mutex * semaphore;
```

and at your constructor initialize the mutex calling his constructor:

```
semaphore = new std::mutex();
```